# Looking for another word to fit into this sentence!

Tags: vocabulary

I dyed my hair green to _____ the coming Halloween.

The tone in this sentence I want to express is passive like "cope".

So instead of saying I dyed my hair green because of the coming Halloween, I want a more passive tone.

I am thinking of using the word "conform" but doesn't know if it's the right fit.

Comment: "prepare for"? What is the reason for the change, with more info we can provide an answer.

Comment: Exactly. Are you dying your hair because it is conventional (*conform*) or for a different purpose?

Comment: You may say "I dyed my hair green in view/anticipation of Halloween".

Comment: I agree more context is need.  If the goal is pure passivity:  I dyed my hair green to *sleep through* the coming Halloween.

Answer (score 2):

I would use **weather**, as if Halloween is a storm and you're just doing what you think you need to do to survive it.

Answer (score 1):

> "I dyed my hair green as a concession to the coming Halloween."

*Concession* denotes yielding reluctantly to a social custom of which you may not approve or couldn't care less about. Is it a passive act? Yeah, sort of. If one's "heart" isn't in the whole costume thing, but one doesn't have the energy to engage in some sort of protest against the custom, well then one compromises and dons a token Halloween disguise.

Put differently, your dyed hair is a *sop* you throw to all those conformists who spend hours coming up with an idea for a costume, and then spend more time (not to mention money) on making, buying, or renting the costume. Perhaps your motivation is to avoid being called a party pooper by those enthusiastic costume wearers. After all, you reason, there is no inviolable law you're breaking with this little concession.

Answer (score 0):

To *conform* with something is to behave according to its acceptable conventions - typically out of social pressure. Per *Oxford Dictionaries...*

> **[conform:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conform)**  behave according to socially acceptable conventions or standards.

So if you're dying your hair because it's socially accepted or to fit in (pointed out by Drew), then *conform* wold work. If not... if you're doing it out of interest then use terms like *celebrate* (chaslyfromUK), *prepare for* (Yeshe), etc.

Comment: Another way to say it: to *fit in*.

Comment: @Drew that's a better way of putting it. My old way *because it's socially accepted* seems slightly derogatory.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the verb, ***observe***:

> to celebrate or solemnize (as a ceremony or festival) in a customary
>   or accepted way

also if you want go even more passive, perhaps ***solemnize***, present in the above defintion, is your ticket:

> to observe or honor with solemnity

Both from Merriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

I think the best match for the tone you describe is **endure**.

> suffer (something painful or difficult) patiently

Answer (score 0):

I will go with **accord** and **fit**.

> accord: to be consistent or **in harmony** :  agree —usually used with *with* : *a theory that accords with the known facts* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accord)
>
> fit:   to be suitable for or to :  harmonize with [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fit)

.